# How can I automatically keep folders clean?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I've just wiped my laptop and am starting to move files back on to it now. How can I keep certain folders clean automatically? For example, is there an easy way to automatically deletes all of the contents in a folder older than 2 weeks, and have this process run daily? That would really help in keeping things like my downloads folder from filling with junk.

This is on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit. Added that to the question. That little detail somehow always slips my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create batch script that deletes content of download folder. And then create windows version of cron and run it on designated intervals.

Batch to delete contents of my folder.

```
FOR /D %%i IN ("D:\myfolder\*") DO RD /S /Q "%%i" DEL /Q "D:\myfolder\*.*"
```

Delete folders older than N

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Forfiles documentation: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

And cron for windows:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: Is there a way to do it with deleting files older than X days?

Comment: @NickAnderegg I updated my answer.